# "Look to get $200 on something" or "look to get on something" in context

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me if I have to use **on** or **for** in the context below?

> Person A: How much are you asking for delivering that load?
>
> Person B: We are looking to get $200 **on**/**for** that one.

Are both possible in the context? If neither is correct what would you say?

Comment: Yes, but remember, asking yes/no questions is off-topic. See the [tour].

Comment: Ok, ignore my previous comment. I see you updated the question. Very cool. :) Either one works for this sentence -- I'm not sure if different dialects favor one over the other, or it's just whatever the individual prefers in that second.

Comment: They are both correct. "On" is more casual/informal, and "for" is neutral/professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"For" is more likely here.  We typically ask "for" a price or "for" an item at a price.

"On" could also be used in a similar sentence, in that the speaker is emphasizing the price that was put "on" several items, and this one is $200.  But even then, the wording "looking to get" makes that a bit confusing. I'd say it is either incorrect or perhaps just a misspoken sentence.  I'd expect person B instead to say, "We have $200 on that one".  But perhaps that is splitting hairs a bit; the wording "We are looking to get $200 on that one" would certainly be understood and not questioned, but the "for" wording is definitely more common.